# Generate Unique 10-Digit Alpha-Numeric Code for Registration

Tags: c#, .net, security

When registering a new account, users must provide an access code which determines what information they have access to. Currently, we create new codes by generating a random number and checking our database to ensure it does not match any existing values. We have performance concerns over this as our database grows.

We'd like a new way to generate these values that guarantees uniqueness without having to query the database to check for existing values.

Our requirements are:

1. Be able to generate multiple access codes for the same piece of data, so that multiple users can access it.
2. Not overly long, we currently use 10 digits, but plus or minus a few is fine.
3. Human readable characters. Today this is restricted to:

   > 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 B C D F G H J K L M N P Q R S T V W X Y Z

Is there something we can do using attributes of the data we are granting access to, such as the primary key(Guid)?

Comment: why 10 specifically? You can't compress guid into 10 characters, minimum 22-24 (as base64)

Comment: Jeff Atwood did a [blog post](http://blog.codinghorror.com/equipping-our-ascii-armor/) about encoding Guids--best they could do was 20 characters, and that was with non-alphanumeric characters.

Answer (score 2):

So, if checking of the code is time-consuming operation, you can simply generate a GUID, which is (almost) guaranteed to be unique, then consider it as 32-char hexademical number, and then convert it to the 29-digit numeral system. Digits in this system would be not 0..28, but your characters - 2,3,4...,X,Y,Z.

GUID is 128-bit number, so in 29-digit system it would be around 26 digits/characters. Yeah, that's much more then 10 digits.

Another approach would be to generate random string, and try to insert into the database as the primary key - very rarely, when you'll receive collision, you receive an insert error, so you can handle it and generate a new key.